# Entering into excel using a UserForm and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, userform

I am trying to use a UserForm to enter data into Excel via VBA. I need the data from the form entered into a Main summary style sheet as well as a newly created sheet. The code I am using is below.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    CME_MACROS.CopyHiddenSheetWithFormattingAndMacros
    CME_MACROS.AddProviderToMain
    
    'Clear input values
    tbxFName.Value = ""
    tbxLName.Value = ""
    tbxAnniversary_Month.Value = ""
    tbxRenewal_Amount.Value = ""
    
    'Notify user that data has been added
    MsgBox "Data has been added to the table."
End Sub






Public Sub CopyHiddenSheetWithFormattingAndMacros()
    Dim templateSheet As Worksheet
    Set templateSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    'Define variables to hold input values
    Dim First_Name As String
    Dim Starting_CME As Integer
    Dim Last_Name As String
    Dim Anniversary_Month As String
    Dim Renewal_Amount As String
    
    'Get input values from user
    First_Name = ufAddProvider.tbxFName.Value
    Last_Name = ufAddProvider.tbxLName.Value
    Anniversary_Month = ufAddProvider.tbxAnniversary_Month.Value
    Renewal_Amount = ufAddProvider.tbxRenewal_Amount.Value
    
    If templateSheet.Visible = False Then
        templateSheet.Visible = True
    End If
    
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=templateSheet)
    templateSheet.Cells.Copy newSheet.Cells
    newSheet.Name = First_Name & " " & Last_Name
    newSheet.Range("B1").Value = First_Name & " " & Last_Name
    newSheet.Range("B3").Value = Renewal_Amount
    newSheet.Range("B4").Value = Anniversary_Month
    
    templateSheet.Visible = False
    newSheet.Visible = True
End Sub


Public Sub AddProviderToMain()
    'Define variables to hold input values
    Dim First_Name As String
    Dim Starting_CME As Integer
    Dim Last_Name As String
    Dim Anniversary_Month As String
    Dim Renewal_Amount As String
    
    'Get input values from user
    First_Name = ufAddProvider.tbxFName.Value
    Last_Name = ufAddProvider.tbxLName.Value
    Anniversary_Month = ufAddProvider.tbxAnniversary_Month.Value
    Renewal_Amount = ufAddProvider.tbxRenewal_Amount.Value
    
    'Insert new row into table
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Providers").ListRows.Add
        .Range(1, 1).Value = First_Name
        .Range(1, 2).Value = Last_Name
        .Range(1, 3).Value = Anniversary_Month
        .Range(1, 4).Value = Renewal_Amount
        .Range(1, 5).Value = Renewal_Amount
    .Range(1, 6).Value = "Test" 

    End With


End Sub
```

When I tried the code above it creates the sheet and adds a row to the main summary sheet. However it doesn't use any of the data entered into the form

Comment: What is CME_MACROS ?

Comment: Do you have any `On Error` statements anywhere?  Do you get any error messages? Does the table `Providers` exist?

Comment: The CME_MACROS is a separate module I set up to house Macros, and I haven't been getting any error messages. When I use the submit button as well the two macros AddProviderToMain and CopyHiddenSheetWithFormattingAndMacros do seem to run because the test value enters in the Providers table and the other does create a new sheet that is a copy of the template sheet. However the data from the form isn't being entered into the fields.

Comment: I found a work around that will work instead putting those two macros in a separate module I just placed them into the form with the btnSubmit_click() routine. This fix will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

From another module you can't get values entered in your form like `ufAddProvider.tbxFName.Value`, so you need to keep it running in the form where controls are accessible.